# Not able to click on "OK" button of facebook popup in Appium iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to automate Facebook signup with my iOS app through Appium iOS. When I click on the Facebook signup button, it takes me to the Facebook permission popup where I have to click the OK button, but I am not able to perform the click operation. I am trying following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("OK")).click();
```

It is working in Android but not working in iOS app.

Screenshot is available on following url 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/e54qevzdosk8n3t/Screen%20Shot%202015-05-11%20at%2012.06.57%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Try using Xpath on iOS, it should work, get the xpath from appium inspector for iOS

Comment: I tried with following xpath but it does not work "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[1]/UIAWebView[1]/UIAButton[1]")).click();"

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to auto-click the OK button? The whole purpose of that page is for the **user** to **voluntarily *give*** you permission. You don't get to just take it yourself. The fact that this is possible on Android is a security vulnerability.

Comment: To complete facebook signup flow it is necessary to click on OK button. So is it possible in iOS app?

Comment: Yes, the **user** must tap the button **with their finger**, *manually*, on the screen. You can't just auto-accept it for them. That's a blatant violation of trust.

Comment: This pop up you mention, is this a webview inside the app or do you leave the application to get the permissions from Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

When we authenticate using Facebook this means is it authenticating using "Oauth". for that there can be three Authentication scenarios using

1. Facebook App.
2. External browser(i.e. safari).
3. Embedded browser.

**In case of Facebook app**: Appuim will not work, as it will redirect to Facebook app and and appium can not handle your app and facebook app with same appium driver.

**In Case of External browser(i.e. safari)**: Again as above authentication will happen on safari browser and appium can not handle your app and safari with same appium driver.

**In case of Embedded browser**: Appium can handle the UI, as ui is part of Application.

Comment: How way we can deal facebook signup operation with custom app.

Comment: what is your use case from the above? If is from first two, you can not control from appium. As for automation it instruments the application for which it required Apple Developer profile. 
We can't get apple developer profile from Facebook. If you can then welcome.

Comment: So it is not possible for iOS....Can you suggest me any automation tool that can perform facebook activity?

Comment: It is a limitation of iOS automation, All the automation tools are using iOS automation framework only, so I think it is not possible in any tool. If you find something please let me too. Thanks an advance.